# I don't know why array is not recognized when I create a string

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't know why array is not recognized when I create a string and type the following code to access it in `MainActivity.kt`:

`var values: Array <String> = resources.getStringArray (R.array.names)`

Comment: Do you have it as `<string-array>` in your xml-file?

Answer (score 0):

Define the data type of array just like below:

**var values = resources.getStringArray (R.array.system)**

Or

just write var values = resources.getStringArray (R.array.names)
It will automatically get the required type.

Define the array like below:-

```
<string-array name="system">
    <item>p</item>
    <item>fdd</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Then i think array has not been defined in the string file.